# Why does a Contact Form fail to work with jinja tags?

Tags: django, jinja2

I can successfully create a contact form with Django (2.1).

When I put the form tags inside with `{% csrf_token %}` inside a `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in a HTML template, I cannot get the "success" page to "fire".

Why would this happen when I use the `jinja` tags?

**Middleware:**

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^$', views.howitworks, name='services'),
    url(r'^$', views.showroom, name='showroom'),
    url(r'^privacy/', views.privacy, name='privacy'),
    url(r'^terms-of-service/', views.tos, name='terms-of-service'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.emailView, name='contact'),
    # path('email/', views.emailView, name='email'),
    path('success/', views.successView, name='success'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from .forms import ContactForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/landing.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'home/landing#about.html')

def howitworks(request):
    return render(request, 'home/landing#services.html')

def showroom(request):
    return render(request, 'home/landing#portfolio.html')    

def privacy(request):
    return render(request, 'home/privacy.html')

def tos(request):
    return render(request, 'home/terms-of-service.html')

# def contact(request):
#     return render(request, 'home/contact.html')

# def login(request):
#     return render(request, 'auth/account/login.html')

# def signup(request):
#     return render(request, 'auth/account/signup.html')4

def emailView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['peterdoh@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "home/contact.html", {'form': form})

def successView(request):
    # return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message to Revs Direct.')
    return render(request, "home/success.html", {})
```

**contact.html**

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block header %}
    {% include 'home/header1.html' %}    
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h3 class="section-title">Contact Us</h3>
<p class="section-description">We d love to hear from you. Please fill in the form below with any queries or questions that
    you may have.</p>

<div class="container wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">

            <div class="info">
                <!-- <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                      <p>A108 Adam Street<br>New York, NY 535022</p>
                    </div> -->

                <!-- <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                      <p>info@revsdirect.com</p>
                    </div> -->

                <!-- <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                      <p>HOLD</p>
                    </div> -->
            </div>

            <div class="social-links">
                <h3>Social Media</h3>
                <a href="#" class="facebook">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="instagram">
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="twitter">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                </a>
                <!-- <a href="#" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> -->
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8">
            <div class="form">
                <!-- <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                    <div id="errormessage"></div> -->
                <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="contactForm">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution using guidance from https://hellowebbooks.com/news/tutorial-setting-up-a-contact-form-with-django/.

In contact.html, I used:

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p>Send me a message</p>
    {% if messages %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <p {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="button primary type=" submit">Send Message</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Then in my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40})
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"
    self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Your email:"
    self.fields['content'].label = "Your message:"
```

and finally, my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import ContactForm
from django.contrib import messages

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import get_template

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('landing/contact_template.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            }
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "[Peter Doherty] New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Peter Doherty" +'',
                ['peterdoh@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank you. Message sent.')
            # return redirect('^$')

    return render(request, 'landing/index.html', {'form': form_class,})
```

It was unclear why the first approach was throwing up an error. This approach works and have tested in. Also, ensure that your email configuration is correct in the settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your form?

```
if form.is_avlid():
    myform = form.save(commit=False)
    # add as per your requirement
    myform.save()
    return statement
```

Comment: I don't believe that is a necessary action. I couldn't find the issue and therefore searched for a working form which I took from here: https://hellowebbooks.com/news/tutorial-setting-up-a-contact-form-with-django/

Comment: Agree, that is not required as it already save those, it was just a method for your convenience. Can I ask you for your traceback? Or the error you are getting?